# What does the $ means in .hprof file android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

After initiating Gc and clicking the dump java heap in android studio monitor, this image below appears:

[image]

What does the $ next to the class DialogFrag like in DialogFrag$1 means?  (DialogFrag is just a class that extends Dialogfragment)

I am supposed only to have one instance of this class, but as you can see next to DialogFrag$1 the total count is 7, does this mean I have memory leak?

**Edit:** this my dialog fragment class

```
public class DialogFrag extends DialogFragment {
     AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> asyncTask;


        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


 AlertDialog.Builder alertdialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());


            alertdialog.setTitle("Solution:");

            View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialogfrag,null);

            final MyView myview= (MyView) view.findViewById(R.id.myview);
            myview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

   alertdialog.setView(view);

  asyncTask=new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
                @Override
                protected void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                     //compute something here 

               }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void param) {
                    super.onPostExecute(param);

                                         getDialog().findViewById(R.id.progress).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    myview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });


            asyncTask.execute();





            alertdialog.setPositiveButton("SHOW", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {


                  if(!(asyncTask.getStatus()== AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED)){
                        asyncTask.cancel(true);
                    }

                    asyncTask=null;


                    dismiss();
                }
            });



            alertdialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                    if(!(asyncTask.getStatus()== AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED)){
                        asyncTask.cancel(true);
                    }

                    asyncTask=null;
                    dismiss();
                }
            });


            Dialog dialog=alertdialog.create();
            dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.MyDialogViewAnimation;

            return dialog;
        }


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            getDialog().getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.TOP);
            getDialog().requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what does the $ next to the class DialogFrag like in DialogFrag$1 means ?

`$number` means anonymous inner class, an example would be `new View.OnClickListener() {...}`.

> but as you can see next to DialogFrag$1 the total count is 7 , does this mean i have memory leak?

Maybe, did you rotate the phone seven times?

Remember to unregister listeners and `BroadcastReceiver`s in appropriate lifecycle methods. Try to avoid static fields.

Comment: actually i looped seven times to show and dismiss from the same instance of dialog fragment , i have an async task inside does this mean that its possible memory leak from asynctask ? although i am cancelling it and setting it to null whenever i dismiss the dialogfragment

Comment: First of all don't create an async task in `onCreateDialog`. That's a UI callback, it's invoked e.g. everytime you rotate the phone. If you really only "compute something here" use other tool than `AsyncTask`, perhaps an [`IntentService`](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html). Then use an [event bus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) to post the result from the service to your UI.

Answer (score 1):

The Class names with `$` represent your **inner classes**.

The nomenclature is `ClassName$InnerClassName`

When you see numbers instead of actual names they are anonymous inner classes created created in your methods.

E.g. `ClassName$1`

**In your case :**

Issue is the definition of your AsyncTask as anonymous class here `asyncTask=new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>()` ... create a separate class and create instances of the class when required.

Comment: but does this means i have memory leak? i was making a loop to show and dismiss a dialog fragment and the memory allocation keeps increasing whenever i show and than dismiss the same dialog fragment ,i have added the dialogfrag code if you could check plz

Comment: issue is the definition of your AsyncTask as anonymous class here `asyncTask=new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>()` ... create a separate class and create instances of the class when required.